# Battery indicator missing (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: gnome, laptop, battery

The battery indicator on my laptop (razr stealth, ubuntu 20.04, gnome)  has disappeared, and if I disconnect AC it dies immediately .  So I suppose this means my battery has reached EOL and that I am SOL ?

Comment: I would try a power reset on the laptop first.  I think on that model you would just hold in the power button for about 15-30 seconds, then power it back on.  Most laptops though should still have a way to replace the battery, even if it is internal without an easy way to eject it.  If a power reset and / or a new battery does not fix it then you would be looking at a problem with the motherboard charging circuit.

Comment: I have a HP Omen laptop with the same issue. I don't think it's a fault of Ubuntu as Ubuntu just reports on the devices that the chips report, and it seems when a battery dies (at least in some laptops) the hardware device just no longer exists. I use the laptop as a desktop 99% of the time, but an internal battery means you can't remove it when it's on AC for long periods so you are just slowly killing the battery over time until like ours, they die. Like is said above, even internal batteries should be replaceable but you will have to find a repair manual or teardown to see what's involved.

Comment: I tried the hard reboot to no avail, so I blv. @codlord is right and I've got a dead battery. I would think the battery would just show up as having low capacity but maybe some threshold voltage has been passed or the like.